# Google login with AWS cognito in angular version 16

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I am using angular version 16 & my requirement is to create sign up/login feature with AWS cognito
Can anyone please guide me how to implement or share any library of npm which supports angular 16

I have already set up AWS cognito and linked with google client id

AWS Amplify is not working as I am facing issue importing module

Module '"@aws-amplify/auth"' has no exported member 'CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.